# The equivalent to pluralising a word?

Tags: verbs, nouns

To turn "pencil" to "pencils" is to pluralise.
To turn a verb into it's 'associated' (?) verb is what?

Example:

"Lease" to "leasing", "look" to "looking".

Is there a word for this? Or are the two words not closely enough associated?

Comment: Turning a verb into a verb is not doing anything to it.

Comment: You need a better account of "associated" verbs before you can ask a question and expect an answer. In the case of the examples you give, the term is **[Inflection](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf)**; the verb root is inflected by the _-ing_ inflectional suffix. _Look_ and _looking_ are different inflected forms of the same verb.

Comment: In that case, inflection is exactly the word I'm after. Thanks. Apologies if the question was unclear.

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't conjugation more specific? Can't other parts of speech be inflected?

Comment: "Conjugation" means [inflecting verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinVerbs.pdf). "Declension" means [inflecting nouns](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf) (and adjectives, which were considered nouns by Latin grammarians). "Inflection" is the general term. These terms are used for inflected Indo-European languages, but there's so little inflection in English that it's hardly worthwhile to distinguish. Plus, having too many terms around simply misleads people into thinking they're all different, and therefore they may be incorrect. Etc.

Comment: Perhaps keep in mind that, in those examples, you are conjugating the verbs specifically into present participles.

Comment: @user61979 or as a gerund, noun or adjective

Answer (score 1):

**Inflect**

When you form a word from a word of the same part of speech (such as a verb from a verb) it is called *inflecting*. The -ing suffix is called an *inflection*.

Answer (score 0):

The word for which you are looking is participialization or gerundization (depending on how the "-ing" is being used).